# Unit testing for a publish method in mass transit using in memory bus

Tags: rabbitmq, masstransit

I am new to MassTransit and messaging. I am trying to write a unit test for a `IBus.Publish` and am not able to succeed with the result.

I am observing the fault from RabbitMQ and my observer looks like this:

```
public class FaultObserver : IReceiveObserver
{
    public FaultObserver(IRequestUpdater statusUpdater,Lazy<IBus> bus)
    {
        this.statusUpdater = statusUpdater;
        this.bus = bus;
    }

    public async Task ConsumeFault<T>(ConsumeContext<T> context, TimeSpan                                    duration, string consumerType, Exception exception) where T : class
    {
    }
 }
```

and my tests looks like the below code

```
var bus = fixture.Freeze<Mock<IBus>>();

bus.Setup(bu => bu.Publish<ReportFailedEvent>(It.IsAny<ReportFailedEvent>(),It.IsAny<CancellationToken>())).Verifiable();

var sut = fixture.Create<ReportRequestedFaultObserver>();
// Act
await sut.ConsumeFault(context.Object,new TimeSpan(0,0,1),string.Empty,exception);

// Assert
//bus.Verify(b => b.Publish<ReportFailedEvent>(It.IsAny<ReportFailedEvent>(), It.IsAny<CancellationToken>()), Times.Exactly(1));
bus.Verify(b =>b.Publish<ReportFailedEvent>(new ReportFailedEvent(request,exception.Message),It.IsAny<CancellationToken>()),Times.Once());
```

my setup looks like

```
[SetUp]
public void SetUp()
{
    fixture.Customize(new AutoMoqCustomization());
    var inMemoryTransportCache = new InMemoryTransportCache(Environment.ProcessorCount);

    bus = Bus.Factory.CreateUsingInMemory(configure =>
    {
        configure.SetTransportProvider(inMemoryTransportCache);
        configure.ReceiveEndpoint("input_queue", configurator => 
        { 
            configurator.Handler<(cc => 
            {
            });
        }); 

    });

    bus.Start().Ready.Wait();
}
```

I am not able to mock my `Publish` method. Does anyone knows what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You should Publish from the `ConsumeContext`, not from the `IBus` - there should never be a reason to inject IBus into your observer.

Comment: Thank You for the quick response.I will try and let you know

Comment: Hello chris I have implemented the context.publish and I took out the DI from my oberver and still my unit test fails.

Comment: Well, I can't explain your unit test I don't use mocks. You can look at the MassTransit unit tests to see how expectations are checked. Without mocking.

Comment: Do you have any link that I can follow.

Comment: Start [here](https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/blob/develop/src/MassTransit.Tests/MultiTestConsumer_Specs.cs), but there are others.

Answer (score 4):

Your mock for the bus is wrong. It should be:

```
bus.Setup(bu => bu.Publish<ReportFailedEvent>(
    It.IsAny<object>(), It.IsAny<CancellationToken>()));
```

Publish takes an `object` and a `CancellationToken`, as per the interface definition in MassTransit:

```
Task Publish(object message, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken));
```

Also, if you want to check the contents of the message, you can use the Moq `Callback` extension:

```
ReportFailedEvent message = null;
bus
  .Setup(bu => bu.Publish<ReportFailedEvent>(It.IsAny<object>(), It.IsAny<CancellationToken>()))
  .Callback<object, CancellationToken>((a, b) => { message = a as ReportFailedEvent; });

//.. your system under test code....

Assert.That(message.Property, Is.EqualTo(expectation));
```

If you are setting the priority, the MassTransit interface looks like this:

```
public static Task Publish<T>(
      this IPublishEndpoint endpoint,
      T message,
      Action<PublishContext<T>> callback,
      CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
      where T : class;
```

And an example would be:

```
bus.Publish<ReportFailedEvent>(message, context =>
{
    context.SetPriority(messagePriority.Priority);
});
```

And the accompanying Moq is:

```
ReportFailedEvent message = null;
bus
  .Setup(bu => bu.Publish<ReportFailedEvent>(It.IsAny<object>(), It.IaAny<Action<PublishContext<ReportFailedEvent>>>(), It.IsAny<CancellationToken>()))
  .Callback<object, Action<PublishContext<ReportFailedEvent>>, CancellationToken>((a, b, c) => { message = a as ReportFailedEvent; });
```

Just as a side note, ideally you should be publishing the interfaces rather than classes, so `IReportFailedEvent` rather than `ReportFailedEvent`.